# Jquery Slider - 'undefined' error

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, slider

So i got this simple script from [bootsnip](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-pricing-slider-donations).

All I wanted was a simple slider so I used this above script although stripped it down a bit, but im getting an undefined error. Could someone please help me with this.

Here is what I got.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
          $("#slider").slider({
              animate: true,
              value:1,
              min: 1,
              max: 10,
              step: 1,
              slide: function(event, ui) {
                  update(1,ui.value); //changed
              }
          });

          //Added, set initial value.
          $("#amount").val(0);
          $("#amount-label").text(0);
          
          update();
      });

      //changed. now with parameter
      function update(slider,val) {
        //changed. Now, directly take value from ui.value. if not set (initial, will use current value.)
        var $amount = slider == 1?val:$("#amount").val();

        /* commented
        $amount = $( "#slider" ).slider( "value" );
        $duration = $( "#slider2" ).slider( "value" );
         */

         $('#slider a').html('<label><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span> '+$amount+' <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></label>');
      }
```

```css
.ui-widget-content {
    border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
    background: #e1e1e1;
    color: #222222;
    margin-top: 4px;
}

.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default{
background:transparent !important;
border:none !important;
}
.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle label{
    background: #E68937;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width:5.2em;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 5.2em;
    height: 100px;
    cursor: default;
    margin: 0 -40px auto !important;
    text-align: center; 
    line-height: 35px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 15px;
    
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle .glyphicon {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    margin: 0 3px; 
    font-size: 11px;
    opacity: 0.5;
}

.ui-corner-all {
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {
    top: -.9em;
}

.ui-state-default,
.ui-widget-content .ui-state-default {
    border: 1px solid #f9f9f9;
    background: #3498db;
}

.ui-slider-horizontal .ui-slider-handle {
    margin-left: -0.5em;
}

.ui-slider .ui-slider-handle {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ui-slider a,
.ui-slider a:focus {
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
}
.skill-slider {
    margin-bottom: 70px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="skill-slider">
  <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
  <div id="slider"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the #amount div to display the value then you must set it to the min value i.e. 1 (not 0) you have supplied to the slider like so:

replace

```
     $("#amount").val(0);
```

with

```
     $("#amount").val(1);
```

The slider won't allow the value to go beyond the min, max range, but it seems you're initializing it beyond the range.

What's happening in this nice piece of code?

```
    var $amount = slider == 1?val:$("#amount").val();
```

Its checking if a parameter (slider) has been passed to the function, if not, then it initializes the slider value to the value present in #amount. 
In the update() call, there is no slider value which is passed, so it tries to read the value in #amount. But the #amount object is not created  in the html. Which is where your 'UndefinedError' is coming from.

Also, If you won't be using the #amount div, then in the document.ready() function, you can use update(1,1) instead of a blank update() to set the value of the slider without reading from the #amount object's value;

This should set up the slider's initial value explicitly:

replace

```
    update();
```

with

```
    update(1,1);
```

and replace

```
    var $amount = slider == 1?val:$("#amount").val();
```

with

```
    var $amount = val;
```

Ideally, you don't want to overload an update() function with init logic.
So this keeps it clean.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing `var $amount = slider == 1?val:$("#amount").val();` but no where in your HTML do I see an item with an attribute `id=amount`.  There could be other issues, but that's the first problem.  (In case you're not familar with jquery, $("#amount") means get the HTML element with the ID of amount; if there isn't one, this will return undefined, which doesn't have a "val" method.  (Also, I don't like using $varname for variables that aren't jquery objects, but that's a personal preference AFAIK)

Comment: Thanks Foon,
I took the script from - http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/bootstrap-pricing-slider-donations

Obviously, I did not clean it well. :)